# Azure Cloud Service IP ranges

Tags: azure, ip, paas

When using Azure Cloud Services (PaaS), if I deploy a solution consiting of N roles, what are their IP ranges? Is it possible to assign IPs from a certain pool to the roles?

What I'm looking for is to have at least 2-3 role instances (of the same kind) with "well known IP addresses" - is this achievable?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear on what you are looking for so I will try to give several answers that can address the range of questions that you might be asking.

1. The VIP (the public IP address) for the cloud service will never change as long as you don't delete the service.  So if you are looking to whitelist your service's IP address then you can use the VIP given for the entire service.  You could also use a [Reserved IP](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/) to allow you to keep the VIP even after deleting the service.
2. If you want to directly address specific instances you can use either `<InstanceInputEndpoint>` which will use the same VIP but assign different port numbers to each instance, or you can use [Public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/) which will assign a different public IP to each instance.
3. If you are looking for the possible public IP range you can use the [Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) list.
4. If you are looking for internally addressable IP addresses you can setup a [Cloud-Only Virtual Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx#bkmk_Cloud_Only) and define a subnet which will give your roles an internal IP address within that subnet.
5. If you want on-prem connectivity and direct addressability to specific role instances you can setup a Cross-premises virtual network.