# Access specific web role node on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a number of Azure Cloud Service deployed (currently Classic, but in the process of upgrading to Extended Support). Each Cloud Service has a web role with a number of nodes (2 or 3 currently depending on the site).  Is there a way to force a web browser to connect to a specific node?  This would be extremely useful to diagnose issues - to narrow them down to a specific node.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370744/azure-cloud-service-ip-ranges.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks - but, no, this doesn't answer my question.  I need to have the load balancing in place, but be able to somehow tell the load balancer which node to route the traffic to (in some special cases). In the past I used haproxy for load balancing and it could, for example, look at HTTP request headers and forward to a specific backend based on their value

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Configure  as per the other SO answer that Gaurav pointed you to.
2. Configure Instance Level Public IPs as per the other SO answer that Gaurav pointed you to.
3. RDP to the instance and connect directly to the DIP.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/troubleshooting-scenario-5-internal-server-error-500-in-webrole for more info.
4. Remove the other instances from LB rotation by setting them to Busy state.  Obviously this wouldn't be a good option for a production service.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team, specifically the SetBusy feature.

Both option 1 and 2 still leave load balancing in place, but they also give additional options to connect to specific instances.  They do require reconfiguration of the cloud service so if that isn't possible for you then 3 or 4 are your only other options.